# A error about converting Python binary to C++ binary in boost.python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I have to convert some binary from Python to C++ by boost::python.The binary maybe come from image or text file.But some error occur for converting the image file's binary into c++.The following is an example.

C++

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::python;
void greet(char *name,char *ss)
{
    std::ofstream fout(name,std::ios::binary);
    std::cout<< "This length is:" << strlen(ss) <<std::endl;
    fout.write(ss.strlen);
    fout.close();
    return;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ctopy)
{
    def("greet",greet);
}
```

python:

```
import ctopy
#It is right.
f=open("t1.txt","rb")
ctopy.greet("t2.txt",f.read())
f.close()

#Do a error.There isn't data in the file "p2.jpg".
f2=open("p1.jpg","rb")
ctopy.greet("p2.jpg",f2.read()) #error.the file "p2.jpg" will be a empty file.
f2.close()
```

How to convert image's binary to c++?

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all, what **exactly** are you trying to accomplish, and what error happens? Edit your question with the required information.

Comment: @StoryTeller,I have writed more.It will creat a error file at last python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the real code, after you created a minimal example from it. Further, which Python version are you using? Anyhow, here's a few things that are wrong in the code you provided:

- You should use `const`, as any C++ FAQ will tell you.
- You are using strlen() on something which isn't even guaranteed to be zero-terminated but which can well contain zeroes in the middle.
- You should use std::string, which doesn't barf if you have internal null chars.
- Closing the file is useless, that is done automatically in the dtor. Flushing and checking the streamstate is much more interesting. On failure, throw an exception.
- Drop the trailing return, it doesn't hurt but it's unnecessary noise.
- Read PEP 8.
- Use a with-statement for reading the files.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding of a [binary file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) generally depends on factors other than the programming language, such as the type of file, operating system, etc.  For example, on [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_395), a text-file contains characters organized into zero or more lines, and it is represented the same way in both C++ and Python.  Both languages just need to use the proper encoding for the given format.  In this case, there is no special process in converting a Python binary stream to a C++ binary stream, as it is a raw byte stream in both languages.

There are two issues with the approach in the original code:

- `strlen()` should be used to determine the length of a null-terminated character string.  If the binary file contains bytes with a value of `\0`, then `strlen()` will not return the entire size of the data.
- The size of the data is lost because `char*` is used instead of `std::string`.  Consider using `std::string` as it provides both the size via `size()` and permits null characters within the string itself.  An alternative solution is to explicitly provide the size of the data alongside the data.

---

Here is a complete Boost.Python example:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void write_file(const std::string& name, const std::string& data)
{
  std::cout << "This length is: " << data.size() << std::endl;
  std::ofstream fout(name.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
  fout.write(data.data(), data.size());
  fout.close();
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("write", &write_file);
}
```

And the example Python code (`test.py`):

```
import example

with open("t1.txt", "rb") as f:
    example.write("t2.txt", f.read())

with open("p1.png", "rb") as f:
    example.write("p2.png", f.read())
```

And the usage, where I download [this](http://www.boost.org/style-v2/css_0/get-boost.png) image and create a simple text file, then create a copy of them with the above code:

```
[twsansbury]$ wget http://www.boost.org/style-v2/css_0/get-boost.png -O p1.png >> /dev/null 2>&1
[twsansbury]$ echo "this is a test" > t1.txt
[twsansbury]$ ./test.py 
This length is: 15
This length is: 27054
[twsansbury]$ md5sum t1.txt t2.txt
e19c1283c925b3206685ff522acfe3e6  t1.txt
e19c1283c925b3206685ff522acfe3e6  t2.txt
[twsansbury]$ md5sum p1.png p2.png
fe6240bff9b29a90308ef0e2ba959173  p1.png
fe6240bff9b29a90308ef0e2ba959173  p2.png
```

The md5 checksums match, indicating the file contents are the same.

Comment: Thank you.But Only one respondent.@doomster answer this question first.